# javascript file object storing/retrieve in cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cookies, file-upload

I am storing File list in cookies so that if I navigate to another page and come back to this page, I want all the files which were selected by user previously.
This code I am using it to store the data in cookies.

```
if(!angular.isUndefined(filelist)) {
                        $cookies.filelist = JSON.stringify(filelist).toString();
                    }
```

Below code I am using to create filelist object from the files selected by user

```
$('#fileupload').on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
                for(var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++){
                    filelist.push(data.files[i])
                }
            });
```

Code to retrieve data from cookies

```
if($cookies.filelist != null && $cookies.filelist != 'undefined'  && $cookies.filelist != 'null') {
                    filelist = $.merge(filelist,JSON.parse($cookies.filelist));
                }
```

When i am storing this filelist object it is of "File" type and when I am retrieve it is of "Object". How can I type cast my object to file object? Is it a correct approach I am following?

Comment: You're not going to be able to do what you're trying to do, I'm afraid.

Comment: please guide me then....what should I do then?

Comment: I am able to get data from the cookies but it is coming as simple object I want it as file type object

Comment: I don't think you can get the browser to save user-selected File references by any means. JSON is not a universal serialization mechanism - all that's happening is that it's saving the simple properties of the file object. You can't turn them back into File objects.

Comment: then how can I implement this functionality?..any work around?..i am using angularjs, jquery file upload in my project.

Comment: You are fighting against basic browser security mechanisms. The only way to get a real File object is for a user to interact with a "file" `<input>` element. Somebody may know a weird trick, but if so it should be reported as a security bug (because it would be).

Comment: What about local storage?..can I store this value there and retrieve it as it is?

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off setting up a file structure on your server for storing the files, then use a database to store the URL of the files, when adding the url to the database you can also add the url to your cookies or in session variables, so when you come back to the page you have all your url's that point to the files. I don't understand why you need the actual file object itself. This is only used by `<input file />` to upload to disk.